# How to implement digital filter that will attenuate the voltage over certain ranges in my voltage-temperature plot

Tags: digital-filter

I have a temperature sensing circuit that has a "somehow linear" output voltage over the range 20-80 °C.

[image]

I plan to use an 8-bit ADC to have a digital representation of the voltages. However, the ADC samples at even periods resulting to the graph shown below:
[image]

The blue points are the "perceived" voltage of the ADC since it must have equal spaces between the levels of the sample. The orange points are the actual output voltage of the circuit above by manually setting the NTC to resistance values as set by the manufacturer on a data sheet. My goal is to design a digital filter that will attenuate certain magnitudes from 35-75 °C so that it will match the blue points.

How do I start? I am knowledgeable of discrete-time Fourier transforms and basic digital filter design however, I am not sure where to start. I plan to:

1. Take DTFT of the orange points
2. Design a digital filter that will attenuate certain magnitudes in the earlier DTFT graph **(If so, how will I know the certain frequencies that need its magnitude response to be attenuated so that the orange points will match that of the blue points?)**

Comment: If you post the numerical values of your measurements rather than a graph, I could generate a lookup table for you in a few minutes and post it in my answer.

Comment: I’m not sure if the DTFT will help here. You can see the voltage/temperature relationship is non-linear. I agree that a calibration table would be an ideal option if you have enough memory.

Comment: @Ryan I am starting to think that it might be better and more precise to use a calibration table rather than a digital filter since the method you and user4574 suggested is much easier to implement while avoiding tedious computations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your goal is to take the ADC output and convert it into the correct temperature value.

You don't need a digital filter.  Digital filters typically change a signals magnitude based on frequency.  But what you actually want to do is get the temperature values based on the ADC reading.  Therefore, what you actually need is a lookup table.

What I would suggest is to create an 8-bit lookup table that transforms your measured ADC reading into the correct reading.  To generate the table, you could use the data points you already have (orange) and the desired values (blue) and linearly interpolate between them using a spreadsheet tool.  Then put those values into an array in your software.

```
//The table should have 256 values
double table[]{
    20.0,
    20.5,
    ...
    80.0    
}


//get the temperature...
temperature = table[adc_value];
```

Comment: Oh, may I ask if you also meant that I must design a combinational circuit that will interpret the output of the ADC in the ranges 35-75 °C (using the values in the interpolation) so that the voltage reading will be precise?

Comment: @qcpz I assume that your ADC is being read by something (microcontroller, processor, FPGA, etc.) that runs code.  No extra circuit is needed.  Just make a table in your software and use it like I showed in the example.

Comment: It might help the OP to look for supporting information if you told him this process was called 'linearisation'.